# How to obtain the same result of Java String.hashCode() in Objective-C?

Tags: java, objective-c, hash, hashcode

I've been reading documentation about String.hashCode() on
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java
Trying obtain an identical result from an identical string, but I did not come up with any satisfying results.
In Objective-C [NSString hash] gives a totally different result.

Have anyone already done this?

Thanks

Comment: Provide the code that you have so far.

Comment: Have you taken into account native byte order can differ across platforms?

Comment: Only senseless code so far, btw I was thinking about incongruousness about different platforms. If so I would be rather have a Java service server-side that calculates that hash instead of calculate it client-side. doh :(

Comment: A mismatch in byte ordering between the platforms will have an impact.  Also the Java implementation of hashcode, while it has not changed in awhile is open to change between Java releases and venders.  If you have the option of asking the server for a hashcode, then that would be an easier and less fragile approach.  Although it would add an extra round trip to the server. If possible, transmit the hashcode with the string if it originated from the server to avoid that round trip.

Comment: If you do carry on with writing your own hash function, make sure that the bytes are equal on both sides and remember that the Java implementation is working with 32bit ints and not chars.  Chars are 16 bit unsigned in Java, while ints are 32 bit signed.  That could throw your code off too.

Comment: Lastly, as a sanity check.  Why do you need the same hash code on both sides?  It is not a common problem to have, and you would be best off if you could design that 'requirement' out entirely.

Comment: Thanks for the advices Chris!
I think I should give one more try and convert it in Obj-c. 
The reason is because as often happen I have to make a brand new iOS client app for a really really old legacy web-app that uses WSDL and this is not going to change for a while. It is a temporary solution, but we don't know when it's going to change (in one month or 2 years maybe!). That's a corporate "Cliché" sadly :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer provided by Alfred is not correct. First of all, hashCode can return negative, so the return type should be a signed integer and not an unsigned integer. Secondly, the charAsciiValue++ is off. In the original Java code, an array index is being incremented, not a unichar. Here is a tested/working version that's a category on NSString:

```
- (int)javaHashCode
{
    int h = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < (int)self.length; i++) {
        h = (31 * h) + [self characterAtIndex:i];
    }

    return h;
}
```

Edit: I originally used NSInteger, but I ran into issues with it. I believe it was due to the machine being 64 bit. Switching NSInteger to int fixed my issue.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfectly! didn't know about the eventually negative value.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated code for swift 4**

```
func javaHashCode(name:String)-> Int{ 
   var nsname = name as! NSString; var h:Int = 0  
   for (index,value) in name.enumerated(){ 
       h = 31*h + Int(nsname.character(at:index)) 
   } 
     return h 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I made an efficient snippet that mimic the Java string.hashCode() result using the math algorithm at the wiki page:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode%28%29#The_java.lang.String_hash_function

```
+ (NSUInteger) hashCodeJavaLike:(NSString *)string {
int h = 0;
int len = string.length;

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    //this get the ascii value of the character at position
    unichar charAsciiValue = [string characterAtIndex: i];
    //product sum algorithm over the entire text of the string
    //http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode%28%29#The_java.lang.String_hash_function
    h = 31*h + (charAsciiValue++);
}
return h;
```

}

hope it help someone!
Keep in mind, as commented by Chris, that if the Java string.hashCode() algorithm is rewritten problems may occur.