# How to replicate java hashcode in C language

Tags: c

I need to implement the exact same logic of java hashcode in C. A sample program in java is below

```
import java.io.*;
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
              String Str = new String("speforums.com");
      System.out.println("Hashcode for Str :" + Str.hashCode() );
     }
}
```

The hashcode for above java example is 262685869. I need the same result in C language.

Using google I landed up here which implements the same in objective C - [How to obtain the same result of Java String.hashCode() in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894642/how-to-obtain-the-same-result-of-java-string-hashcode-in-objective-c)

Comment: Why? AFAIK that is an internal implementation detail of the JRE. if you want to hash strings, use a common algorithm like MD5 or SHA1.

Comment: It is not efficient to use cryptographic quality hashing as SHA1 for algorithms like just a hash set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

... and may the source be with you, Luke

```
                int h = 0; // added for clarity

1496            int off = offset;
1497            char val[] = value;
1498            int len = count;
1499
1500            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
1501                h = 31*h + val[off++];
1502            }
1503            hash = h;
```

The `offset` and `count` are offset and length of the string content in the char buffer. It need not start at 0, neither span till the end of it.

The source code is from OpenJDK [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java) but it is supposed to return identical values. It is Java, not C, but if you know C you should be able to understand and convert.

This is for `String`. The default hash code of an object is derived from the object address in Java Virtual Machine. There is no way (and most likely no any sense) to replicate this.

Answer (score 2):

The specific behavior of [`Object.hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) is not defined, but [`String.hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode()) is.

> The hash code for a String object is computed as
>
> ```
> s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]
> ```
>
> using int arithmetic, where s[i] is the ith character of the string, n is the length of the string, and ^ indicates exponentiation. (The hash value of the empty string is zero.)

Though [the code for it is rather different](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/String.java#String.hashCode%28%29).

```
public int hashCode() {
    int h = hash;
    if (h == 0 && value.length > 0) {
        char val[] = value;

        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            h = 31 * h + val[i];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

That can be directly translated into C.

```
int java_hashCode(const char *str) {
    int hash = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
        hash = 31 * hash + str[i];
    }

    return hash;
}
```

Comment: Java's `char` is equivalent to an **unsigned** integer whereas C language's `char` may be unsigned OR **signed** dependending your implementation so your char value can be **negative**

Comment: @Gugelhupf Yes, but this is for strings. And strings in C are `char *`.

Comment: Hi @Schwern, the result of `java_hashCode(const char *str)` will be **33** for `[1, 2]` and `[-2, 95]` . Demo here: https://ideone.com/yez0JD

Comment: @Gugelhupf Is that a problem? There's a hash collision, but one of those is an invalid string. What would the solution be?

Comment: It can be a problem for someone who only sees the `const char *str` parameter signature, or the one who try to use this function with **non-ASCII** compliant chains. Generally, hash functions in C are implemented with the `unsigned` integer types. In order to replicate Java hash for "strings", we have to implement Java's String encoding first and work with `uint16_t` I guess